# NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object test.OnCollisionEnter (UnityEngine.Collision col) (at Assets/test.cs:81)

Tags: c#

В общем, я хочу, чтобы когда мой игрок касался кое какого объекта, то на экран выводил You Win. Так вот, You Lose, HP и Score отлично работают, но, когда приходит момент, когда экран должен написать You Win выводит эту ошибку "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
test.OnCollisionEnter (UnityEngine.Collision col) (at Assets/test.cs:81)
"
Вот весь код.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class test : MonoBehaviour
{
public int HP;
public int Score;
public float Fall;

public Text HP_text;
public Text Score_text;
public Text YouLose_text;
public Text Win_text;
void Start()
{
    HP = 100;
    Score = 0;

    HP_text = GameObject.FindWithTag("HP").GetComponent<Text>();
    Score_text = GameObject.FindWithTag("Score").GetComponent<Text>();
    YouLose_text = GameObject.FindWithTag("YouLose").GetComponent<Text>();
    Win_text = GameObject.FindWithTag("Win").GetComponent<Text>();
}


void Update()
{
    HP_text.text = "HP:" + HP;
    Score_text.text = "Score:" + Score;

    if (HP > 100)
    {
        HP = 100;
    }

    if (HP < 0)
    {
        HP = 0;
    }

    if (HP <= 0)
    {
        YouLose_text.text = "You Lose";
    }

    Vector3 Checkpoint = new Vector3 (0,2,0);
    GameObject Player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
    Fall = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform.position.y;
    if (Fall<-4) 
    {
        HP -= 10;
        Player.transform.position = Checkpoint;
    }
    
}

private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.tag == "Coin")
    {
        Score += 1;
        Destroy(other.gameObject);
    }
    if (other.tag == "MedKit")
    {
        HP += 10;
        Destroy(other.gameObject);
    }
}

private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
{
    if (col.gameObject.tag == "You Lose")
    {
        YouLose_text.text = "You Lose";
    }
    if (col.gameObject.tag == "Win")
    {
        Win_text.text = "You Win";
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Win_text   null,  скорее всего в инспекторе ничего туда не вставлено

Comment: всё вроде вставлено

Comment: Ну ошибка говорит, что не может обратиться к элементу, т.к. он null. Смотри тогда через отладку, что и где какие элементы у тебя null